# Custom transition when adding a view controller to an other

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I use this category to add a UIViewController inside another:

```
@implementation UIViewController (Container)

- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController parentView:(UIView *)view
{
    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
{
    [self containerAddChildViewController:childViewController parentView:self.view];
}

- (void)containerRemoveChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
{
    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}

@end
```

It works well, but I would like to change de default transition (fade-in / fade-out) when I add or I remove an UIViewController.

I tried to do something like this but the rendering is ugly.

```
myVC.view.alpha = 0;
[self containerAddChildViewController:myVC];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    myVC.view.alpha = 1;
}];
```

I read a lot about how create a custom transition for UIViewController but the way how I add a view controller is not the main common way. So I would like have advices on how can I change the transition using this category.

Thanks !

Comment: - (void)containerRemoveChildViewController:   in this method                 [UIView animateWithDuration:9 animations:^{
    childViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}];    Like That you can also set Alpha of 1.0 in - (void)containerAddChildViewController Method. And Remvoe After finished animation.

Comment: It doesn't work well. The two animations are playing in the same time. :(

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a copy.jpg"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 5.0;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -85, 440, 635);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}
- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navi;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but in your code you show how add an UIImageView. But I want to add an UIViewController. It's not the same things ! And, I need to use the category presented in the main post of this topic. I want that the method viewWillAppear is trigged when I add the UIViewController.

Comment: Sorry, As i know ViewWillAppear will be triggered while the view loads or when we pop/Dismiss to that view controller. i hope you will find a good answer for this question. I'll also try this scenario.